# Dynamic column name throws ORA-01722:invalid number

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

This is a generic format for my actual problem. I am passing a column name so as to get amounts according to sub heads.

Lets assume table XYZ for table of different sub head fields with respective years officewisely like

```
id, office_id, subhead1, subhead2, subhead3, year
```

Now, what is happening is the parameter `test_column_name` is not working. It works fine when I manually place some field over there. I throws error:

```
"ORA-01722:invalid number"
```

My function goes like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION  (test_column_name in varchar)
RETURN float
IS
    AMOUNT float;
BEGIN    
    SELECT 
    SUM(AMOUNT) INTO AMOUNT FROM TEST_TABLE
    where
    TEST_FIELD IN 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT test_column_name FROM XYZ_TABLE WHERE XYZ_YEAR='2012'
        );  
    return AMOUNT;    
END TEST_FUNCTION;
/
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Do you mean `WHERE TEST_FIELD IN()` Instead of `AND TEST_FIELD IN`

Comment: You have a datatype mismatch somewhere. Post the datatypes for your columns. Is TEST_FIELD a numeric data type?

Comment: yeah, TEST_FIELD is a numeric data type, and the test_column_name is also numeric data type, but test_column_name holds the column name

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to achieve? Do you want to dynamically decide which table column to filter against? Then you need a different approach. Please post some example input and expected output.

Comment: Yeah, table column gets dynamic which comes from test_column_name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can't put 'test_column_name' into the SQL directly. You should use dynamic Sql.

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM TEST_TABLE  WHERE TEST_FIELD IN (SELECT DISTINCT  '||test_column_name||' FROM XYZ_TABLE WHERE XYZ_YEAR=''2012'')'
        INTO AMOUNT;
```